# Wordpress Plugin To Show Open Graph Read News Application On Facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have a basic idea about open graph and that it has come up with new to interact our blogs or news websites to come up on Facebook under news section.

I am developing a micro news website on wordpress (i have already almost completed the designing part!). My question is can anyone basically guide me to a plugin and/or tutorial to get this done so as if the prople read articles and news on the website it can be shown under the news section of his profile on facebook. Coz let's all agree this is one cheap form of advertisement and i dont want to miss on it!

Comment: Where's the programming question?

Comment: the bsic question right now is is this even possiblein wordpress and best way to do it . If I cant find any plugin or extention then comes the programming part !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use wordpress,

You can use the suite Facebook AWD all in one with the sub plugin Facebook AWD all in one Opengraph actions

You can find it here => http://facebook-awd.ahwebdev.fr
And the list of sub plugins => http://facebook-awd.ahwebdev.fr/plugins/

Action news.reads is configured on this website, you can test it. Loggin into the site using Facebook, And read some pages. After 11sec on a page the plugin will push the action on your timeline and store activity on your site to allow users to manage it.

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this DIY for adding og: meta tags to your wordpress blog.

http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/facebook-open-graph-meta-tags/

Once you have that done, then you can use the Facebook like and Facebook comments plugins (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins) on your articles.